# JavaScript Validation cannot insert into the database

Tags: php, javascript

okay i had to rephrase my question, my javascript codes cannot proceed to the next step which is isset['submit'] it just stuck there. im really hoping someone here can help my correct my javascript code so that it will successfully call the isset and run my php code to add it to the database.

my php code

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$firstname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['fname']);
$lastname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['lname']);
$age = mysql_escape_string($_POST['age']);
$gender = mysql_escape_string($_POST['gender']);
$email = mysql_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$nickname = mysql_escape_string($_POST['nickname']);
$regflag = 0;



$sql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{

        if($row['email'] == $email)
        {
            echo '<b> The email is already taken!</b>'; 
            $regflag = 0;
        }
        if($row['nickname'] == $nickname)
        {
            echo '&nbsp;<b>The nickname is already taken!</b>'; 
            $regflag = 0;
        }
}

if($regflag == 1)
{

    $regsql = "INSERT INTO accounts         VALUES('','$firstname','$lastname','$age','$gender','$email','$password','$nickname','MEMBER',now())";
    $query = mysql_query($regsql);
    echo '<body onLoad = "regsucess()"> </body>';
}
```

}

my javascript code

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function validator(){

    if(!document.register.fname.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your first name.');
    document.register.fname.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(!document.register.lname.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your last name.');
    document.register.lname.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(!document.register.age.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your age.');
    document.register.age.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(!document.register.email.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your email.');
    document.register.email.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(!document.register.password.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your password.');
    document.register.password.focus();
    return false;
    }
    if(!document.register.nickname.value)
    {
    alert('You need to supply your nickname.');
    document.register.nickname.focus();
    return false;
    }


register.action = "register.php"
document.register.submit();
//alert("Congrats!");


}
```

Comment: Provide html code that you are using...

Comment: Run it in Firefox with the web console up. What errors does it give?

Comment: Also, where is your database connection? You should be using `mysql_real_escape_string` unless you are using a version of mysql below 4.3? `mysql_escape_string` has been deprecated. Of course most people will tell you to use prepared statements, which are better to use.

Comment: it doesnt have errors it just loads up and nothing happened...

Answer (score 0):

Why 
`register.action = "register.php"` and not
`document.register.action = "register.php"` ??
also if you call this from onclick of a submit button or from onsubmit, then remove the last line
`document.register.submit();`

Lastly if ANYTHING in your form has `name="submit"` you will not be able to call the submit event from script

Here is what I would expect to see

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function validate(theForm){

  if(!theForm.fname.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your first name.');
    theForm.fname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!theForm.lname.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your last name.');
    theForm.lname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!theForm.age.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your age.');
    theForm.age.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!theForm.email.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your email.');
    theForm.email.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!theForm.password.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your password.');
    theForm.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(!theForm.nickname.value) {
    alert('You need to supply your nickname.');
    theForm.nickname.focus();
    return false;
  }
  return true
}
</script>
```

Using

```
<form action="register.php" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should duplicate (at least) the code that you use is Javascript in the PHP code for the insertion into your database. In fact the code for the insertion should be tougher - Javascript stuff is to pick up the usual suspects (typos etc) and to give the user a better experience.

Just ensure that the Javascript code is less harsh than the PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with mplungjan.

Can you show us the form html code? Maybe the submit input has a different id than 'submit'.